# I can't use the model in angular

Tags: angular

I'm a beginner in Angular4 and I have a problem to use my own example-module named "ex" and its component 'app-ex' in my project.

The browser logs this message: "Template parse errors: 'app-ex' is not a known element"

This is my project: https://github.com/ndsvw/exampleangular
You just need to

```
npm install
npm start
```

I tried to declare the ex-component instead in my app.module and it works. But I want to import the whole module.
What's the fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export your component in the module. Also don't have to add the component and module in the component when you already imported it in the module.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ExComponent } from './ex.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [ExComponent],
  exports: [ExComponent]
})
export class ExModule { }
```

Remove:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
//import { ExComponent } from './ex/ex.component';
//import { ExModule } from './ex/ex.module';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
```